# Building Objective-C Command Line App?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, command-line

I'm kinda new to Objective-C and I have a basic app I'm tinkering with in Xcode that simply reads all calendar events (using EventKit) and then reformats the data and dumps it as a json encoded string.

I can get the code to run and return the data correctly on my iMac (in Xcode), but my Macbook Air returns no results using the same calendars (synced through iCloud). It also runs and returns results on a friends machine (in Xcode). If I build the app and run it from the command line, I get no results, even on the machines that it does work properly in Xcode.

Is there something extra that I'm missing here? This is the code I currently have. Can someone give me some kind of pointer as to what to try next to get this to work? I just can't figure out why it works on one machine and not the other, and why it works in Xcode and not from the command line.

Thoughts?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <EventKit/EKEventStore.h>
#import <EventKit/EKEvent.h>
#import <EventKit/EKCalendarItem.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
        NSCalendar *currCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

        NSDateComponents *oneDayAgoComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    oneDayAgoComponents.day = -1;
        NSDate *oneDayAgo = [currCalendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDayAgoComponents
                                                  toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                 options:0];

        NSDateComponents *oneYearFromNowComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    oneYearFromNowComponents.year = 1;
        NSDate *oneYearFromNow = [currCalendar dateByAddingComponents:oneYearFromNowComponents
                                                       toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                      options:0];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:oneDayAgo
                                                            endDate:oneYearFromNow
                                                          calendars:nil];

        NSArray *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

        int i;
        int eventCount = (int)[events count];
        NSMutableArray *formattedEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        for (i=0; i<eventCount; i++) {
            NSDictionary *dict = @{
                               @"title" : [[events objectAtIndex:i] title],
                               @"starts" : [[[events objectAtIndex:i] startDate] description],
                               @"ends" : [[[events objectAtIndex:i] endDate] description],
        };
            [formattedEvents addObject:dict];
        }


        NSArray *eventArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:formattedEvents];

        NSData *jsondata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:eventArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsondata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        printf("%s", [jsonString UTF8String]);

        return 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's a directory issue.  When you run in Xcode you have your current directory set one way, and likely different when you run on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a sandbox issue. I had to go check the EKAuthorizationStatus of EKEntityTypeEvent's to determine if the app had access to the events and if not, request it.

Seems odd that it requested access initially from within Xcode with no issues on my iMac but never did on my Macbook but, oh well. Fixed.